# Undertstanding Cup products

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory

I am trying to understand cup products from the following notes and am having some difficulty understanding theorem which in a way defines cup product for cohomology: [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf#theorem.1.9.5](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/groupcoh.pdf#theorem.1.9.5)

What does it mean to say that the map 'cup products'
$$H^i(G, A)\otimes _{\mathbb Z} H^j(G,B) \xrightarrow{\smile} H^{i+j}(G, A \otimes _{\mathbb Z}B)   $$
is "natural on $A$ and $B$" ?
And how do we get the commutative diagram on the top of page 37  ( [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf#page.37](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/groupcoh.pdf#page.37) ) ?
I believe it has something to do with the 'naturality'.

Any help is appreciated and feel free to give any reference.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the usual notation for the cup product is given by the command `\smile` (which produces $\smile$), so I changed your question accordingly.  If this is not what you want, please feel free to revert back to the command `\cup` you were using.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you. I was actually not aware of this as both these notes that I have mentioned and Milne's notes on CFT which I have been reading use `\cup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means naturality in the sense of category theory.  Saying the cup product is natural in $A$ means that for any $B$ and any map $f: A \to A'$ you get induced maps $H^i(G, A)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H^j(G, B) \to H^i(G, A')\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H^j(G, B)$ and $H^{i+j}(G, A\otimes_\mathbb{Z} B) \to H^{i+j}(G, A' \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B)$, and the square formed by these maps and the cup product commutes.

$\delta$ here is the connecting homomorphism arising from whichever short exact sequence is under consideration. The vertical maps in the diagram at the top of p.37 are $\delta \otimes 1$ on the left, and $\delta$ - arising from $0 \to A \otimes B \to A \Uparrow \otimes B \to A^* \otimes B \to 0$ (1.9.4), on the right. Commutativity is precisely the identity (ii) of 1.9.5.

Comment: Ok. I understand what natural means in this context. It appears to me from your answer that the diagram on the top of page 37 indeed comes from naturality. But I do not understand where do we get a map $A^* \rightarrow A $. I know we do have the snake lemma map $H^i(G,A^*) \rightarrow H^{i+1}(G,A) $

Comment: A map from A to A* wouldn't give the diagram you want - that's not the right thing to look for